# How to record locations with IP geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, geolocation, ip-address

I have a script using the Geolocation DB script that tracks the user's location based on their IP. I'm new to this and looking for a way to record the locations that were tracked so I can see them.

This is the script/HTML.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span></div>
    <script>
      $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
         .done (function(location) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
            $('#state').html(location.state);
            $('#city').html(location.city);
            $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
         });
    </script>
```

So it will show the location *for* the user on *their screen.* I need a way to see it though. How would I go about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. I have corrected this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
       .done (function(location) {
          $('#country').html(location.country_name);
          $('#state').html(location.state);
          $('#city').html(location.city);
          $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
          $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
          $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
       });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>State: <span id="country"></span></div>
<div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
<div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
<div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
<div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
<div>IP: <span id="ip"></span></div>
```

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, but i meant that while it will show them their location like the script demonstrates, i don't know how to see their location/the IP that was tracked.

Comment: To track down user location and other information you can  use Mixpanel or Google Analytics tool.